# Storing Logs in a Mongo database using NLog

Tags: xml, mongodb, nlog

I have been trying to use NLog.Mongo and NLog.MongoDB to write logs to a Mongo database. However, I keep getting an error saying "This is an invalid xsi:type 'http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd:MongoDB". The code I am using is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>   
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
  autoReload="true"
  throwExceptions="false"
  internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.MongoDB"/>
  </extensions>

  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="MongoDB" name="mongo" database="NLog">
      <field name="timestamp" layout="${date}"/>
      <field name="level" layout="${level}"/>
      <field name="message" layout="${message}"/>
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="mongo"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

I am either looking for a solution to this error or another way this could be performed. I have searched everywhere I can think of and only found unanswered questions such as:

[NLog xsi:type not working with custom target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065459/nlog-xsitype-not-working-with-custom-target)

[Nlog with MongoDB connection and target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594437/nlog-with-mongodb-connection-and-target)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error that comes up is only specifying that it isn't a recognised type of NLog. The extension does actually work, it turns out the problem with the code above is due to not specifying the connectionString.

I have fixed the problem using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
  autoReload="true"
  throwExceptions="false"
  internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Mongo"/>
  </extensions>

  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="Mongo" name="mongo" databaseName="NLog" collectionName="Test" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/NLog"/>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="mongo"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: Note that the `databaseName="NLog"`, `collectionName="Test"` and `/NLog/` of connectionString are all optional. If excluded default values will be used. (NLog will be used as the database name, Log will be used as the collection name). The necessary part is just the `connectionString="mongodb://localhost"`

Comment: Will do. (says I can't do that until tomorrow)